# null value in entry:otherFileOutputs=null. NDK is missing a "platforms" directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I run the program, I get a gradle build error:

> null value in entry:other File Outputs=null

When I click in *see complete output in console* on my gradle console I can see this:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>   Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>   NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
>   If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Mindu Laptop\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
>   If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

I am not using NDK and in my `local.properties` i have

```
#This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.  

#Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!

# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Tue Apr 18 16:25:21 NPT 2017
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Mindu Laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

Things that i have tried:

1. Clean project/Rebuild Project
2. Invalidate caches and restart

Edited:Fixed,In my case it was due to white space in the location of the sdk

Comment: There might be a real bug as well; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127636 June 3 2017 it was reported again with  3.0.0 and got the reply For people experiencing this with plugin 3.0.0+, please file another bug .

Comment: in my case not all machines actually had NDK installed. once that was fixed, all was well.

Comment: Even i hadn't installed NDK so it was hard to know what was that error.but when i changed my sdk location containing no space in file name the problem was solved.